# How do I setState from toggle checkbox?

Tags: react-native

The setState is not working when I am trying to use the onToggle from the checkbox to set the state to true.

I have tried to console log the function and it works except that the state won't change.

```
import CircleCheckBox, { LABEL_POSITION } from 'react-native-circle-checkbox';

const MyTaskItem = (props) => {

    return (

        <CircleCheckBox
            checked={props.taskDone}
            onToggle={props.onToggleCheck}
        />

    );
};
```

```
import MyTaskItem from "../../components/MyTaskItem";

export default function MyTasksScreen() {

  const [taskDone, setTaskDone] = useState(false);

  const checkDoneHandler = () => {
    setTaskDone(true);
    console.log(setTaskDone);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <MyTaskInput visible={isAddMode} onAddTask={addTaskHandler} onCancel={cancelTaskAdditionHandler} />
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        data={myTasks}
        renderItem={itemData =>
          <MyTaskItem
            id={itemData.item.id}
            onDelete={removeTaskHandler}
            title={itemData.item.title}
            description={itemData.item.description}
            onToggleCheck={checkDoneHandler}
          />}
      />
      <AddTodoButton onPress={() => setIsAddMode(true)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I want to change the state on taskDone to true/false when toggling the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to change specific task state, so first of all, you need to pass the ID of the task which toggled, so `MyTaskItem` can be rewritten like this:

```js
const MyTaskItem = (props) => {
    const {taskDone, id, onToggleCheck} = props;
    return (
        <CircleCheckBox
            checked={taskDone}
            onToggle={()=>onToggleCheck(id)}
        />
    );
};
```

Then you should handle items states in your `MyTasksScreen`. 
Since `FlatList` is a `PureComponent`, therefore you need to pass the changing states to the `extraData` property of the flatlist, to inform item states has changed.
In case you want to change all items `done` state, you can do like this:

```js
export default function MyTasksScreen() {

  const [taskDone, setTaskDone] = useState(false);

  const checkDoneHandler = () => {
    setTaskDone(true);
    console.log(setTaskDone);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <MyTaskInput visible={isAddMode} onAddTask={addTaskHandler} onCancel={cancelTaskAdditionHandler} />
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        data={myTasks}
        extraData={taskDone}
        renderItem={itemData =>
          <MyTaskItem
            id={itemData.item.id}
            onDelete={removeTaskHandler}
            taskDone={taskDone}
            title={itemData.item.title}
            description={itemData.item.description}
            onToggleCheck={checkDoneHandler}
          />}
      />
      <AddTodoButton onPress={() => setIsAddMode(true)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use TypeScript.

From the code you've added, looks like you're not sending `taskDone` to your `MyTaskItem` Component.

Also, try adding `console.log(taskDone)` after this line: `const [taskDone, setTaskDone] = useState(false);`

Comment: Can you share some resources to use typescript with RN?

Comment: [RN documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/typescript)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice this, but why you advise hem to use typescript?